# Can't load options into dhtmlxCombo

Tags: combobox, dhtmlx

Can't load options into dhtmlxCombo. I try the following:

```
myForm = new dhtmlXForm("dhtmlxForm"); 
myForm.loadStruct("codebase/form.xml"); 
var combo = myForm.getCombo("xVolumeStatus");
combo.load("codebase/options.xml");
combo.selectOption(2, false, true);
```

But combo is undefined

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forget callback. Twice 
It must be:

```
myForm.attachEvent("onXLE", function() {
    var combo = myForm.getCombo("xVolumeStatus");
    combo.load("codebase/options.xml", function(){
        combo.selectOption(2, false, true);
    });
});
```

First you getting combo when form is loaded, then you select option when combo options are loaded.